# How to control one window from another in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

I'm trying to control one window from another in HTML5. I'd like it so when I open one window that I log into, and another window that I login to, then from one window I can click a button and something happens in the other window. I'm not sure where to start; can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: HTML5 is a Markup Language to define a document structure. Your question is about program logic. You should provide more relevant information. EG. What do you mean by "log-in to a window"?

Comment: you mean [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#crossDocumentMessages) ?

Comment: Logging into the window would simply be a way of identifying the session you would be controlling. Ideally i would like to use a button in one browser window with a listener in another window really to control elements in an HTML5 canvas object. Hope that is a little bit more clear, i need to be vague as i cant give away too much sorry

Comment: I think Knu is on the right lines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need any HTML5-Features for that but you can easily do it with javascript:

`myNewWindow = window.open()` opens a new window and assigns a `window`-object of that new window to `myNewWindow`, so you can easily access the new window's DOM from the opening script, using the `myNewWindow`-variable.

It also works the other way: In a script in the new window, you can user `window.opener` to access the `window`-object and DOM of the opening window.

Just make sure, that the content of all your windows is loaded from same domain, as javascript does not allow you to control content loaded from another source (refer to "same origin policy" for more information on this topic).

Comment: Unfortunately i wont be able to call it from the same frame, the other window that i would control from could be opened on a completely different machine or device

Comment: You are not looking for an HTML5 feature - you need a server based system to push commands from one device to another. Check out http://nodejs.org for a nice system to write publish/subscribe systems in.

Comment: In this case you can either poll the server with repeated ajax-requests for new commands (there are libraries for that approach). Or, if you explicitly asking for an HTML5-feature, make yourself familiar with WebSockets which allow you to open a bidirectional connection between server and client. WebSockets are not supported by all browsers, however.

Comment: I have been looking at cross document messaging however i am unsure if i can achieve what i want without opening the pages in an iframe or a popup.

Comment: the method window.open() in tml5 won't work properly...
You can't control the size and the position of it. It will display 
a new full-screen window to u. I encounter the same problem.
@Simon    Have you found that how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This answer is 6 months late, but for the Googlers (like me):

I would recommend WebSockets for what you're trying to do Jonathan. WebSockets allow the server to broadcast data to any/all browser windows that are open for your page/site in realtime.

Browser support is currently [quite poor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) but there are good shims to get it working across all browsers very efficiently. [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is one such solution which I've used to great success.